# Issue with using images as buttons or links

Tags: html, image, button

So I'm sure this is a common problem and question but I can't think of a good way to search for it on here or in Google but here's what I'd like to know.

When you use an image for a button or link and the graphic itself is say, a circle or triangle, and doesn't fill up all corners of the rectangular image.  Is there a way to keep those blank or transparent corners of the image from being part of the active link?

Basically, how do you make only the graphic the active link or button and not the whole img element?  If someone could point me toward a tutorial or even give me a name for this issue, I'd certainly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called an image map. Check it out:

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was thinking I was going to have to do.  I was just wondering if there was a better way to do it. Thanks for the advice.